# Currency Converter

Tags: product, price, currency, conversion

We have a problem in our webshop that the currencies switch with each other.
The prices are Swedish Krona and Euro (we have two separate websites where the currencies are used). 
Only some products have the wrong price, and it's never both of the currencies that are wrong. It's either that the Euro price shows in Sek or the Sek in Eur.

For example: A product should cost €49.90 and Sek 499 but for all of a sudden it changed to €499 and stayed Sek 499. Another product cost €129 and Sek 1290, it stayed €129 but changed to Sek 129. This has happened to several products without any relation to each other (like category, color, season etc), just random products. It also happened out of nowhere and new products keep changing price all the time.

Has anyone had this problem before? What causes it?

I hope I made any sense.

Thank you!